# Reduce JavaScrip Array of Objects based on boolean property value

Tags: javascript, object, boolean, reduce

I'm trying to reduce the following data from video info into a custom Object structure that removes "label" keys duplicates but also keeps true all the encountered features that are available.

The initial data looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "label": "4320p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "2160p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "2160p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1440p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1440p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  }
]
```

As you can see there are many Objects for a single resolution label but some of them have HDR while others have 60fps while other might have none of them or just both.

What I'm trying to do is to reduce this array with the following reduce function.
Assuming that `resolutions` is the above Object:

```
resolutions.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if (!unique.some((obj) => obj.label === o.label)) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
  }, []);
```

That gives me the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "label": "4320p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "2160p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1440p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  }
]
```

But if you look closer you'll see that during the reduce operation some booleans are merged with the first element value for each unique label key and I need to have in the end the true feature enabled even if just one of them was true.
The `2160p` label is a good example where there actually is an object that has `HDR: true` but in the end I just get it as `false`

Do you have any idea on how to manage this situation with modern JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you first grouped by `label` using the `.reduce` and in each iteration:

- If `label` is not in `acc` yet, add the first object (current item)
- Else, update the features of the stored category in a way that if one of its feature is not available and the new current item in this category has it, set it to `true`

In the end, return the grouped list of objects with merged features:

```js
const resolutions = [
  { "label": "4320p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "2160p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "2160p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1440p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1440p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1080p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1080p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1080p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "1080p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "720p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "480p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "480p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "480p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "480p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "360p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "360p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "360p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "360p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "240p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "240p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "240p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "240p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "144p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": true } },
  { "label": "144p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "144p", "features": { "HDR": false, "60fps": false } },
  { "label": "144p", "features": { "HDR": true, "60fps": false } }
];

// update category's features if any is not available yet, and the new object has it
const _getUpdatedFeatures = (currentFeatures={}, newFeatures={}) => {
  const updatedFeatures = {...currentFeatures};
  for (let [feature, currentlyAvailable] of Object.entries(currentFeatures)) {
    if(!currentlyAvailable && newFeatures[feature]===true) {
      updatedFeatures[feature] = true;
    }
  }
  return updatedFeatures;
}

// group by label and merge features availability
const res = Object.values(resolutions.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const { label } = item;
  const prev = acc[label];
  if(!prev) 
    acc[label] = item;
  else 
    acc[label] = { ...prev, features: _getUpdatedFeatures(prev.features, item.features) };
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Interesting solution and it works, just wondering if there is a more concise way to do it within the `reduce()` function.

Comment: Can you clarify more on what "concise" means here? The idea of updating the features can be done in any type of loop, but I did it like this for the sake of clarity

Comment: Just without the separated `_getUpdatedFeatures()` function, I've been reading the Docs for the `reduce()` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) but there are some concepts within the parameter callback that I cannot fully understand yet but I think might come in handy. Anyway it works as it is right now and I thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your approach you could use the following. You would need to extend the `if` statement in case you have preferences which element should be kept in case there are two elements one with HDR set to `true` and one with 60fps set to `true` (with this version in this case the first resolution discovered would be selected):

```js
const resolutions = [{
    "label": "4320p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "2160p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "2160p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1440p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1440p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "1080p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "720p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "480p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "360p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "240p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": true
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": false,
      "60fps": false
    }
  },
  {
    "label": "144p",
    "features": {
      "HDR": true,
      "60fps": false
    }
  }
]


const result = resolutions.reduce((unique, o) => {
  const uniqueResolution = unique.find((resolution) => resolution.label === o.label)

  if (!uniqueResolution) {
    return unique.concat(o)
  } else if (uniqueResolution.features.HDR && uniqueResolution.features['60fps']) {
    return unique
  } else if (o.features.HDR && o.features['60fps']) {
    // swap element since there is a better one
    return unique.map((resolution) => {
      if (resolution.label === o.label) return o
      return resolution
    })
  }

  return unique
}, [])

console.log(result)
```